# How can I __scrape__ a password protected website using beautifulsoap and python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, lxml

https://khaiexch.com/ How can i **scrape** this website.
I am trying something like this but it is giving 403 as response

```
login_url = 'https://khaiexch.com/login/login_action'
login_data = {
    "email": "***", 
      "password": "****", 
    "compute": "****",
    "submitted": "****"
    }
r = requests.post(login_url, data=login_data)
```

But the above code is giviing me 403 error , Can any one please guide me how can I **scrape** this website?

Answer (score 2):

Try requesting with `get` method and use headers aswell that would be something like this:

```
import requests

login_url = 'https://khaiexch.com/login/login_action'
login_data = {
    "email": "***", 
    "password": "****", 
    "compute": "****",
    "submitted": "****"
    }
headers     = {'User-Agent': 'okhttp/3.12.1'}
r = requests.get(login_url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
result = r.status_code
print (result)
```